# How to prepend a big DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to `prepend` a huge DIV block, which can be seen at the bottom of the question.

My current idea would be to put inside **one**

```
$('#content').prepend();
```

and break each like up, when I need to insert the content of a variable. That would be all the places which says `TMPL_VAR`

The code would be quite hard to maintain and read.

Is there a clever way to do this?

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input name="anchor" value="<TMPL_VAR ID>" type="hidden">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cellData">                                                          <TMPL_VAR ID>                                  </div>
    <div class="cellData"> <input name="title" id="<TMPL_VAR ID>_title"      value="<TMPL_VAR TI>" type="text" />                  </div>
    <div class="cellData"> <input name="owner" id="<TMPL_VAR ID>_owner"      value="<TMPL_VAR OW>" type="text" />                  </div>
    <div class="cellData"> <input name="from"  id="<TMPL_VAR ID>_begin_date" value="<TMPL_VAR BD>" type="text" class="datepick" /> </div>
    <div class="cellData"> <input name="to"    id="<TMPL_VAR ID>_end_date"   value="<TMPL_VAR ED>" type="text" class="datepick" /> </div>
    <div class="cellData cellRadios"> <input name="ctype" value="individuel" type="radio" <TMPL_VAR IN>/> Individuel <br> <input name="ctype" value="course" type="radio" <TMPL_VAR CO>/> Course </div>
    <div class="cellEdit"> <a href="javascript:showhide('<TMPL_VAR ID>');">Members</a> <input value="Save" type="submit">                 </div>
  </div>
  <div id="<TMPL_VAR ID>" style="display: none; background-color: #fff8e7;">
    <div class="rowMembers">
      <span>
    <label> Users  </label> &nbsp; <input name="users"  id="<TMPL_VAR ID>_users"  size="35" value="<TMPL_VAR US>" type="text" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <label> Groups </label> &nbsp; <input name="groups" id="<TMPL_VAR ID>_groups" size="35" value="<TMPL_VAR GR>" type="text" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would personally go for [jQuery.tmpl()](http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/) to handle this sort of issue.

This way you could specify a template like so:

```
   <script type="text-x-jquery/template" id="template"> 
    <form action="" method="post">
      <input name="anchor" value="${id}" type="hidden">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cellData">                                                          <TMPL_VAR ID>                                  </div>
        <div class="cellData"> <input name="title" id="${id}_title"      value="${ti}" type="text" />                  </div>
        <div class="cellData"> <input name="owner" id="${id}_owner"      value="${ow}" type="text" />                  </div>
        <div class="cellData"> <input name="from"  id="${id}_begin_date" value="${bd}" type="text" class="datepick" /> </div>
        <div class="cellData"> <input name="to"    id="${id}_end_date"   value="${ed}" type="text" class="datepick" /> </div>
        <div class="cellData cellRadios"> <input name="ctype" value="individuel" type="radio" ${in}/> Individuel <br> <input name="ctype" value="course" type="radio" ${co}/> Course </div>
        <div class="cellEdit"> <a href="javascript:showhide('${id}');">Members</a> <input value="Save" type="submit">                 </div>
      </div>
      <div id="${id}" style="display: none; background-color: #fff8e7;">
        <div class="rowMembers">
          <span>
        <label> Users  </label> &nbsp; <input name="users"  id="${id}_users"  size="35" value="${us}" type="text" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label> Groups </label> &nbsp; <input name="groups" id="${id}_groups" size="35" value="${gr}" type="text" />
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    </script>
```

and then with jQuery populate the template with

```
  $('#template').tmpl(myData).appendTo('#myContainer')
```

which will insert the populated template into `#myContainer` given that you have data in the javascript scope `myData` wich corresponds to the data format specified in the template, and that you have defined a html element with an id of `myContainer` which is appendable.

Comment: This looks very interesting! I assume `<script type...` means it should be included in the HTML file. Can the template be included directly in my JavaScript file?

Comment: Yes you can inline html right in javascript and the compile the template though `$.template('myTemplateId',myTemplateContents)` which will then create a named template which you can refer to as 'myTemplateId'.  So it depends on how you wish to order your code. Do you want HTML in your javascript files? or do you want <script> tags in your HTML files? Personally i'd go for the latter. There are also some performance issues you need to be aware of when compiling templates in javascript.

Comment: Use the script tags. In a good editor you are then able to make it highlight everything in those script tags as HTML.

Comment: I wasn't aware that I could access content from the `<script>` tags. Great. I will do that then =)

Comment: Thanks for the bump, and im only happy to help.

Comment: @netbrain And you most certainly did =) In what format should `myData` be in? I have tried `$('#template').tmpl({ "id" : "555", "in" : "checked" }   ).prependTo('#content');` and this crashes...

Comment: start with looking at the jquery examples written by the author and try them out yourself. its easy once you have done it once or twice. but very difficult the first time around. that is why i suggest you try a simple example first.