# Is there better way to write this in Javascript and JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="video">
  <span class="videoNewIcon"><img src="somenewicon.gif"  width="26" height="11" /></span>        
  <a class="videoThumb" href="somevideoname.aspx">
    <img src="http://somesite.com/someimagename.jpg"  alt="description" longdesc="rtmp://somertmp.com/someapplication/mp4:somevide.f4v"/>
  </a>
  <span class="videoTitle">some title</span>
  <span class="videoInfo videoInfoViews"><strong>some views</strong></span>
  <span class="videoInfo videoInfoUpTime"><strong>some up time </strong></span>
  <span class="videoInfo videoInfoCategory"><strong><a href="some category.aspx">some category</a></strong></span>
  <span class="videoInfo videoInfoDuration"><strong>some duration</strong></span>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".video").hover(
    function () {
      $(this).oneTime(1000, "hide", function () {
        $(".videoThumb").children("img").show();
        $("object").remove();
        $(this).children(".videoThumb").children("img").hide();
        var href = $(this).children(".videoThumb").attr("href");
        var longdesc = $(this).children(".videoThumb").children("img").attr("longdesc");
        $("<object classid='clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000' width='180' height='135' id='videoHolder' align='middle'><param name='movie' value='videoHolder.swf?vid=" + longdesc + "&url=" + href + "' /><param name='quality' value='high' /><param name='bgcolor' value='#000000' /><param name='play' value='true' /><param name='loop' value='true' /><param name='wmode' value='window' /><param name='scale' value='showall' /><param name='menu' value='true' /><param name='devicefont' value='false' /><param name='salign' value='' /><param name='allowScriptAccess' value='sameDomain' /><!--[if !IE]>--><object type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='videoHolder.swf?vid=" + longdesc + "&url=" + href + "' width='180' height='135'><param name='movie' value='videoHolder.swf' /><param name='quality' value='high' /><param name='bgcolor' value='#000000' /><param name='play' value='true' /><param name='loop' value='true' /><param name='wmode' value='window' /><param name='scale' value='showall' /><param name='menu' value='true' /><param name='devicefont' value='false' /><param name='salign' value='' /><param name='allowScriptAccess' value='sameDomain' /><!--<![endif]--><a href='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash'><img src='http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif' alt='Get Adobe Flash player' /></a><!--[if !IE]>--></object><!--<![endif]--></object>").appendTo($(this).children(".videoThumb"));
      });
    },
    function () {
      $(this).stopTime("hide");
      $("object").remove();
      $(this).children(".videoThumb").children("img").show();
    }
  );
});
```

Basically what I have is a `<div class="video">`, *onhover* of which I replace `<a class="videoThumb">` with an image to a flash player with movie preview. I inserted a jQuery timer to create a delay so once I hover over `div.video`'s first one will stop playing before the second one starts.

Comment: Looks clean to me. Is it running slowly? What exactly is the question?

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: That there are lots of hacks, like removing object on both triggers. Sometimes IE's getting high with it...

Comment: Hard to tell what's being asked here.  I did notice that you're using $(this).children(".videoThumb") a lot in a single context (function), which is kinda wasteful. If speed is the problem then maybe assigning $(this).children(".videoThumb") to a var and using the var throughout your function would get you a bit more speed, as it reduces the number of jQuery lookups you're doing.

Comment: GordonM, i swap image with flash movie on hover over div containing all items. I have few hacks in code to prevent some random effects in certain browsers. So is there a way to speed up the thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [jquery template](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) in this instance.

Check out my answer here [How to prepend a big DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176331/how-to-prepend-a-big-div/6176352#6176352) for an example usage.

Comment: How would you do that? Why should i rely on beta technology?

Comment: I've personally used it, and it works great. It makes your code much cleaner and you dont have to mix javascript and html code. You can have html code in your html files and javascript in your js files.

Comment: So overall it makes your code much cleaner and more maintainable.

Comment: Thanks for example, question is what will users without JS support get rendred?

Comment: Depends on how much you want to template. you can make it template only so much that it will behave as your already existing code. Is it a requirement to support users without JS support? in that case i would provide an alternative html output with `<noscript>` while taking full advantage of the templating framework.

Comment: While thinking about it, i need to parse DataResult from website's Cache to whatever format jQuery Templates accept. Isn't it a waste? I can get maintainability but parsing result from Cache or DB to JS accepted object notation?